# How to quantify colors in an image like Google does (somewhat)?

Tags: php, image, algorithm, colors, color-space

I've been searching this for a long time now and I want to know if any of you has some kind of resource or knowledge of some kind of algorithm that can take an image and return the percentage of most significant colors in an image. But not any color, I want to make the percentages fit with a predefined constant palette of 12 colors (the same you use in image search on google for sorting).

However, the script I made works in the sense that it gets the colors that are most PRESENT, but not necessarily most significant.

[image: Sample image]

For example, take this image of the first black hole. It has mostly only black with some smudges of red/white/yellow/brown colors. But in proportions these are considered as almost nothing by checking only their amount.

Example: red = 1%, yellow = 3% and black = 96% (not exact values but accurate).

The problem is that even though they are not the most in amount, they are clearly the MAIN colors in the image as for how the human eye sees them. Is there an algorithm for that or a technique? Thank you for reading.

Comment: It is a very complex topic, in imaging processing. I do no think we can give there a complete answer (too long). Short answer: you detect subject, and you remove background. The large part of near every images is background, so not useful.The problem: often there are different backgounds (lawn, shrubs, sky, just on simple case, house, windows, doors, car, lawn, ..).

Comment: This is really big-complex one, I would advice you to **divide** this question into tens of questions , if and only if you need to get the answer from stack-over-flow.

Comment: Yes :P. That is why I asked if there are any resources or articles or whatever online about this. I've been scouring and found nothing that fits. There is no way any one can answer completly here.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your image has resolution WxH.

You say you have a palette of 12 colors.

In order to make an algorithm that sort this colors based on how much they appear in the image, you could create 3 variables:

- A global counter **counter** of valid colors within the image;
- array of **frequencies** with length equals to palette size;
- array of colors representing the **palette**.

A possible algorithm could be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < W; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < H; j++){
        Color dif = new Color(255, 255, 255, 1);
        Color currDif;
        int minIndex = -1;
        for(int k = 0; k < palette.length; k++){
            currDif = palette[k] - image[i][j];
            if(dif > currDif){
                dif = currDif;
                minIndex = k;
            }
        }
        if( CloseEnough(dif, palette[minIndex]) ){
            frequency[minIndex]++;
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, to verify the percentages, one can just:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    print("Color i appears (Palette[i] / counter) %");
}
```

I considered if you find a color that is not close enough to any color in the palette, you ignore it, but obviously you can consider it by simply incrementing the **counter** anyway, so these colors will be the percentage left.

The functions `CloseEnough` and `<` are of your choice to make, but they could work like this:

```
bool CloseEnough(Color c1, Color c2){
    return abs(c1.r - c2.r) < 30 && abs(c1.g - c2.g) < 30 && abs(c1.b - c2.b) < 30;
    //note that 30 can be quite small
    //this value can be modified based on testing and result quality
}

//the closer to black a color is, the smaller it will be
bool < (Color c1, Color c2){
    return (c1.r + c1.g + c1.b) < (c2.r + c2.b + c2.g);
}
```

There may be better solutions out there, but hope it helps.